# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() throws CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS even when all the kernel arguments are set (only occurs on the CPU on macOS)

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been contributing to an OpenCL program called mfakto that trial factors [Mersenne numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) for GIMPS. It uses a modified Sieve of Eratosthenes to create a list of potential factors and then uses modular exponentiation to test the factors. The sieving step can be done on either the GPU or CPU while the modular exponentiation step is done only on the target device.

The program uses different kernels depending on the number's size. I'm able to initialize the [15-bit kernels](https://github.com/Bdot42/mfakto/blob/master/src/barrett15.cl) without issues. However, `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` throws a `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS` error for [32-bit kernels](https://github.com/Bdot42/mfakto/blob/master/src/barrett.cl) even though I've set all the arguments. Here's a sample 32-bit kernel:

```
__kernel void cl_barrett32_76(__private uint exponent, const int96_t k_base, const __global uint * restrict k_tab, const int shiftcount,
#ifdef WA_FOR_CATALYST11_10_BUG
                           const uint8 b_in,
#else
                           const __private int192_t bb,
#endif
                           __global uint * restrict RES, const int bit_max65
                           MODBASECASE_PAR_DEF         )
{
    ...
}
```

In normal circumstances, the kernel takes eight arguments. `MODBASECASE_PAR_DEF` adds a ninth argument that is only used when the application is compiled with certain debug flags. I traced the code and verified that `clSetKernelArg()` is used to set each argument at least once.

The issue only occurs when the OpenCL code is run on the CPU on macOS. It does not come up when the program is run on an AMD GPU or on any device on Windows.

Apple's OpenCL implementation only supports a kernel work-group size of 128 on the CPU, but I've already added checks to prevent `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` from trying to use more local threads than the kernel allows.

I realize this is a very specific problem in a very complex application, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `int192_t` and `int96_t` coming from, and what are they defined as?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue might be related to the `int96_t` and `int192_t` types you are using. Are those `typedef`s for structs? The OpenCL standard is not clear on the use of non-primitive, non-buffer types as kernel arguments, so you will often find this working for some implementations but failing for others.

I suggest putting the data for these arguments in OpenCL buffers, and declaring them in the kernel function signature as `constant int96_t*` or `global int96_t` and similar. You'll obviously need to dereference the pointer in the kernel, either on every use of the value or when copying it into a `private` variable once.